# Does YouTube delete videos based on number of dislikes?

Tags: youtube

I wanted to know if YouTube delete a video if it reaches a certain number of "dislikes"?

For example, some videos are disliked by many people lets say 10,000 people and 20 likes, does YouTube want to delete such video?

Comment: Related: [What are YouTube comment downvotes used for?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99144/147505)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google doesn't care whether people like or not a video. Google profits from people viewing the video so even highly disliked videos might be profitable for Google and they wouldn't want to take them down.

There is no evidence that Google removes videos with many dislikes. There actually is a list with the [most disliked videos on Youtube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-disliked_YouTube_videos) that are still viewable.